# How to use different external images to wordpress without importing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

I'm exporting a 20,000 post into a CSV file from an API made with NodeJS.

All the posts have images with external links each post could have a different link from the other, for example:

```
{
 {
  id: 1,
  images: "http://server-1.com/img.jpg"
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  images: "http://server-2.com/img.jpg"
 }
 ...
}
```

What I need to do is importing those posts without uploading the images into media uploads folder **wordpress default** and just use the links as it's.

I'm using **WP All Import pro** which is a great plugin but unfortunately downloading the images instead of using the links directly like as I need.

Comment: Please include [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you have so far.

Comment: you would have to find the bit in WP All Import pro that imports the images and then sets the image src to the url of your uploads folder, delete (or comment out) all of that and set the src directly to the external url. I don't have a copy of that plugin so I can't be more specific